# How do I differentiate the many varieties of brake/shifter cables?

Tags: parts

I am fixing several old road bikes (all with stem shifters) and I have noticed an abundance of different types of brake/shifter cables. One set of cables that purchased I had to file down to make them fit

I need to buy some cables/housing/ferules in bulk, as well as some brake levers.

How do I differentiate the many varieties of brake/shifter cables, as well as the appropriate types of housings so I can purchase the right equipment to fix these old bikes?

Comment: Downvoted already?

Comment: read  https://www.bikeman.com/bicycle-repair-tech-info/bikeman-tech-info/1641-cables-a-housing and shop online.

Comment: Sounds like you went to the local carbon-fibre roadie shop, or a sports shop, not a true LBS.  I've been there, had a $50NZ voucher to use and ended up with about $20 worth of stuff had I bought from my usual.  Gear cable was $10 up from $4 at the LBS, for the same brand.

Comment: For old bikes, you generally want to go to a place which either is known for rehabbing old bikes, or the mechanics are old enough to be retired. College campuses are actually a decent place to find these people, since a lot of students are running old bikes and you're likely to find the corresponding mechanics there as well (even if they're not old enough to be retired, chances are they learned some of the intricacies).

Comment: This shall explain the downvotes: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You are getting downvotes because the question has three issues. First, it's too broad (you ask about varieties, why no standardization, and what to buy). Second, one of those is a product recommendation/shopping question which quickly becomes obsolete. Third, your question is phrased in a way that is highly opinionated, to the point it was flagged as "rude or abusive".  Please take the [tour] and see the [how to ask](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page. I've edited your question down to the main question reflected by the posted answers.

Answer (score 6):

You can easily buy shift (Compressionless/Index compatible) housing and brake (conventional helical) housing in bulk -- most bike shops buy it by the roll (of about 40-50 meters). Note most housing is shift only or brake only, and you should **never** use shift only housing for brakes (it will break). With non-index shifting though, you should be able to get acceptable performance with using brake housing for shifting. Expect to pay 1-2 USD per meter in bulk.

Note that there are housings that are suitable for both index shift and brake, such as some made by Nokon (but these are expensive; about 50 dollars/ meter).

Ferrules you can also buy in bulk -- you can easily buy them in little tubs of 100 or so for a few cents a piece.

Brake and shift cables will need to be bought individually (in the sense that you can't buy a roll of them and cut them yourself; you can obviously buy big lots of them at a discount). This is because you need to have the cable ends attached so that they can hook into the shifter/brake lever, and this needs to be done at manufacturing time. There are different varieties for different shifter and brake types. This is partially due to manufacturers, and also the different styles of the shifters/brakes. It's not a big deal -- no different really than needing a few different parts for working on a Honda than on a Ford, but you just need to know which ones you need.

These days the shift+brake cable types are relatively standard (since Shimano/SRAM are the vast majority of drivetrains out there): Most non-flat bar bikes (e.g. drop bar road bikes) will use the same brake cable (A) in the figure below, and most flat bar bikes (many hybrids/ mountain bikes) will use (C) for their brakes. And most bikes will use (D) for their shifting.

The people who need (B,E) would know a priori that they need them (since they spent a lot of money on their Campagnolo drivetrains).

Note that many Shimano/SRAM cables are sold double ended -- one has the road end on it, the other has the mountain end. You just cut off the end you don't need and use it as you would if it only came with the proper end.

[image]

(Figure from [Bikeman](https://www.bikeman.com/bicycle-repair-tech-info/bikeman-tech-info/1641-cables-a-housing))

For some classical shifters/brake levers (old Suntour, for example), the original cables used different ends than whats on the market now (e.g. a shift cable with a  ball end with diameter of the similar radius to (D) rather than (D)). In these cases, it doesn't hurt to do a google search to see what people are running for those cables. Or, take it to the shop -- they should have a copy of Sutherland's handbook which will tell them what the right cable is for practically anything. In some cases, you may end up filing another cable end down anyway (which isn't ideal, but sometimes it has to be done). Back in the old days, there were a bunch of manufacturers of stuff and things weren't as standardized as they are now (since Shimano has overrun the market, and SRAM is Shimano compatible for a lot of things).

---

A few remaining points:

- With older (pre index shifting) setups it doesn't make much difference with quality of cables/housings (particularly for shifting) and carefulness of installation. But you might see a perceptible difference if you install cables/housings poorly on modern (index shifting) setups or use poor quality stuff.
- The retailer you buy your stuff from can make a huge difference in price (also, what kind of bikes you have, which determines how much housing and stuff you need). I think I spent about 10 USD a bike last time I did this.
- It probably doesn't make sense to buy bulk rolls of housing -- it's going to take forever to get through it for most people in a non-shop setting, and it takes up space. You don't need to replace them that often, and for one or two bikes, 50 m may be enough to last you close to the end of your riding life.

---

Further reading: [Sheldon Brown's](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/cables.html) always good. This page from [Bikeman](https://www.bikeman.com/bicycle-repair-tech-info/bikeman-tech-info/1641-cables-a-housing) in the comments is useful too.

Comment: "It probably doesn't make sense to buy bulk rolls of housing" - So true. I fix a lot of old bikes (just a guy working on bikes out of my garage for neighborhood kids mostly). I buy two or three full cable/housing sets, and then 5-10 cable only sets. The cable/housing sets usually have enough spare housing to do multiple bikes. Plus, I am frequently able to re-use old housing.

Comment: Not sure everyone with Campi will know they need B and E ends - old bikes can be very cheap to buy, Its fairly easy for a novice on a budget to end up with an old but very high end bike by accident.

Comment: @mattnz - It'd be pretty hard to find a Campy bike even by accident afaik. And if they do, chances are they aren't the type that will be changing the cables themselves.

Answer (score 4):

There are three major brake cable ends, and two gear cable ends.

They are quite separate so that users are less-tempted to use a gear cable where a brake cable is required.

[image: From http://www.myronsmopeds.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Bicycle-Cable-Ends.jpg]

Note the left three are brake cables and are slightly thicker, the right two are gear cables and are thinner.  (Also those numbers are probably stock or catalogue codes and are meaningless here.)

Likewise - note that Brake housing tends to be spiral wound (one single piece of metal coiled like a slinky), and gear housing tends to be compressionless (with tens of separate rods that go lengthwise down the outer housing)

[image: From https://maxthecyclist.files.wordpress.com/2015/10/housingtypes.jpg]

Note that compressionless brake housing is appearing more, but is still not advised to interchange with gear housing because of the outer width difference, so the cable stop frame brazeons don't fit so well if you use the wrong size.

Separately, Shimano is different from Campag because of marketting and exclusiveness.  Make your part slightly different and the users have to buy it from you, to begin with.  Makers can get away with a lot if the difference "adds stiffness or lightness" to their product.

I've never figured out why MTB brake ends are so much different from road brake ends - might be something to do with the motorcycle levers originally used, and then it becomes a normalised tradition.

If you're working on **old** bikes then modern standards go out the window.  Anything old enough is going to be different just because they're old.

**Don't file down braking components** to make them work - that's a plain bad idea.  You don't want to be the cause of an accident or even vaguely implicated.

Buying housing in a box and cutting it to length is a good plan, but it would take me years to use a 100 metre box.  Same goes for 100 boxes of inner cables.

We don't generally recommend brands or shops here but I've had excellent results with [Lifeline kits](http://www.wiggle.co.nz/lifeline-essential-gear-cable-set-shimanosram/) which are enough to do a brake or gear recable for one bike.  You will need a proper cable cutting tool and something pokey to reopen ends.  (I use a generic "superscrew".)  Sometimes a file helps too.

Comment: I disagree on filing down the brake cable ends. Sometimes it has to be done, esp. if you can't find the right cable. But you might need to be careful.